# Cocoa - AVPlayer does not rewind to beginning properly

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avplayer

in one of my MacOS applications I use `AVPlayer` to playback audio files (wav and air files). I am not using `AVAudioPlayer` because of some benefits (observe current play position...) of `AVPlayer`.

I experience a very strange thing when rewinding. I observe the even `playerItemDidReachEnd`. In this method I rewind my player:

```
- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {

    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
    [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero]; //set to 00:00

}
```

This works pretty good but noticed with some wav files that start right at 0 that the rewind as implemented cuts a little bit off from the beginning.

In other words if I play first time all sounds good. The sounds comes to the end and the code shown resets the cursor to the beginning. If I play the second time you can hear that the beginning is slightly off. My current workaround is to simply reload the complete file but that takes time which I wanted to avoid.

Anyone experienced this before and has a solution ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `seekToTime:toleranceBefore:toleranceAfter:` instead?  It claims to enforce accuracy.

Comment: thanks @PhillipMills for you comment. Just tried `[p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];` which did not help either.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution to this one?